# Why Is my UISlider Thumb Image Being Shown Multiple Times and Not Disappearing As They Should?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, slider, uislider

This slider is possessed: 
[Slider http://gorgando.com/possessedSlider.jpg](http://gorgando.com/possessedSlider.jpg)

Whenever I enter "editing mode" for the tableview or leave "editing mode" a duplicate thumb image will appear where the thumb is. It is now behaving consistently in this way. If I switch back and forth from editing mode I'll get lots of thumb images like the screenshot shows.

This is the code that I use to create the slider (in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method):

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(20, 42.0, 280.0, 22);
self.slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.slider.continuous = YES;
self.slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
self.slider.maximumValue = 5.0;
self.slider.value = 0.0;
[[interestCell contentView] addSubview:self.slider];
```

Appreciate any thoughts you might have!

[I just edited/updated this to reflect the questions/suggestions I received but it's still having problems].

Comment: What method is that code snipit from?

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath because the slider is within a tableviewcell. This particular code snippet is only called once when the row/section are appropriate.

Comment: BTW, if your `slider` is declared as `retain`, then you have a memory leak. (You're retaining an `alloc`'d object, but not balancing the `alloc` with a `release`...)

Comment: I do have it declared as retain, but I also have it releasing in my dealloc(). Is that not the appropriate way to do it?

Comment: by assigning it into the property (`self.slider = ...`), it's getting retained twice.  Once by your call to `alloc`, and again by the setter (since it's a `retain` setter).  You're only releasing it once in `dealloc`.  You should probably assign it to a local `UISlider*` variable, configure it, then set the property with the local variable, then release using the local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out!

I had to move my code to the viewDidLoad method except for setting the slider to the contentView, which happens in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method still. What a strange problem that was. Thanks to those who helped and commented!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding it to the cell's contentView and not the cell itself.

Comment: I added it to the contentView and the only difference is that now the possessed behavior is quite consistent. Every time I click the edit button to put the table in editing mode, I get a duplicate thumb image, and I also get one when I take it out of editing mode. Any other thoughts?